# Direct flights to USA from countries with Ebola outbreak

Tags: air-travel, usa, health, africa, event-based-effects

According to [this survey](https://www.scribd.com/doc/242388876/NBC-News-Online-Survey) 58% of Americans think there should be a travel ban on flights from countries where the Ebola has broken out. The survey doesn't make clear what a travel ban would mean, but assuming the USA has no power to ban flights that don't start or end in the USA, how many direct flights are there to the USA from the only countries currently experiencing widespread transmission: Liberia, Sierra Leone and Guinea?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there are none.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is (a) about current events, and any answer will be outdated very soon, and (b) it's purely speculative, not meant to address anyone's real travel issue. If someone is concerned about traveling to/from a country with Ebola, a specific question about that could be asked.

Comment: a) We've had plenty of current event questions (riots in Egypt), and b) there's plenty of CDC, WHO and US State Department documented concepts of travel ban possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

A quick search [from the capitals of the three countries to NYC or MIA](http://www.kayak.com.au/flights/cky,rob,fna-nyc,mia/2014-10-15-flexible) shows no direct flights.  Almost all of them stop in Morocco or somewhere in Europe, before continuing on to the US.

However, and ignoring how effective a travel ban may or may not be on stopping Ebola, what it would consist of is [written up quite well in this National Geographic article](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/10/141007-ebola-travel-ban-restrictions-health-world/).  It would prevent travellers symptomatic who have been in those countries from being allowed to travel to the United States.

Of course, symptoms take 2-21 days to appear (same article)....so again, it may not be as effective as hoped.

Comment: Skyscanner does it one better: http://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/us/sl/cheapest-flights-from-united-states-to-sierra-leone.html?rtn=1

Comment: The survey specifically asked about a "travel ban on _flights_ from countries where the Ebola virus has broken out" which is different than the travel ban discussed in the National Geographic article which would keep out travelers from those countries.

Comment: Eh? It repeatedly talks about 'travel from Liberia etc' (sub-headline) and  'travel from the Ebola zone' - ie flights from countries where Ebola has broken out. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkMayo That was sort of the point of my question. As well as this survey, I've seen lots of comments online about banning _flights_ from these countries--just look at the comments section at the bottom of the National Geographic article. The reality is that there are no direct flights to the USA from these countries so there are no flights to "ban". A travel ban on _travelers_ from these countries could be possible though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they mean travel. So if you've travelled from, say, Liberia to Morocco, and then try and board a flight to the US, they'd stop you travelling.  Like when I have a 'flight' from Christchurch to London even though it's 3+ stops.

Comment: Great question, btw!

Comment: It still doesn't make complete sense to me. AFAIK, screening is already taking place in Liberia and Sierra Leone so if someone is already symptomatic, could they board the plane today? If not, how would a “travel ban for symptomatic people who have been to those countries” differ from the current measures? How would it be implemented and enforced?

Comment: You go out of your way to interpret this charitably but to me, all this sounds more like a knee-jerk reaction from the usual suspects than a well thought-out policy proposal. Short of stopping flights that do not exist or outright banning people with a certain passport even if they are not symptomatic (and even then, could you deny travel to people who have been to the area but are US citizens?), I still don't know how a “travel ban” could look like concretely.

Answer (score 4):

There are no direct flights from those 3 countries.

There are direct flights from Senegal and Nigeria, and these 2 countries have had a few cases of Ebola, but they are all of people who were in contact with people who've come from the 3 outbreak countries, the transmission is under control, and it's not spreading in the general population.

Source: http://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/ban-flights-countries-ebola-outbreaks

> The fact is, U.S. airlines don’t fly to the countries with ongoing
>   Ebola outbreaks. Delta used to fly to Monrovia, but stopped in August.
>   Today, only Delta and United offer direct, nonstop service between the
>   U.S. and West Africa, according to Airlines for America, a trade group
>   for U.S. airlines—Delta to Lagos, Accra, and Dakar, and United to
>   Lagos alone.